# Apply curve to range of numbers - easing a gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to apply an ease to a panning gesture, so the further I pan my finger, the less my effective panning distance is - so I can make it feel like the object I am panning is on a spring.

I guess I need to apply some sort non-linear of curve to the distance I am panning. Pseudo-idea below:

RAW POINTS PANNED
1  -  25  -  50  -  100

'CURVED' POINTS PANNED
1  -  20  -  35  -  45

I'll then use the 'curved' pixels panned to move my UIViews.

I appreciate this may come across as bit vague, I'm not really sure how best to describe it. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated, I can try to describe my problem better if anyone needs.

Comment: Are you looking for something physically accurate or just any kind of easing or something that matches those numbers you have supplied as closely as possible?

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the CURVED POINTS? This seems similar to a parallax effect. Or maybe just a simple log function

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. It doesn't need to be physically accurate, it's just to add a bit of 'candy' to the way the interface interacts. There is no upper point, but I could calculate one if required. Essentially, the range would be from where touch began, to the edge of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like x^n, 0 < n < 1

Raw points panned = x

Curved points panned = x^n

Then you could experiment with different values of n. eg. x^0.8 would give roughly:

Raw points panned = 1 - 25 - 50 - 75 - 100

Curved points panned = 1 - 13 - 23 - 32 - 40

I'm not very familiar with objective-c, but if you have the variable rawPointsPanned, you could convert that to curved points panned with something like this (using java code sorry):

```
curvedPointsPanned = (int) pow(rawPointsPanned, 0.8);
```

Comment: Hi mate, That sounds great, but I'm afraid I'm a bit too 'noob' to understand how to translate that into a working objective-c method. Any chance you could help?